# How to configure Apache 2.x to evaluate PHP rather than serve it as HTML?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I want to serve php files using this tech-combo:

- ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- apache 2.4.18
- php 7.0.3

I installed both apache and php from source using shell commands configure and make.

Installation went smoothly.

I make-installed apache here:

```
~/apache/
```

I make-installed php here:

```
~/php/
```

The php install placed a shared library in the apache tree:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dan dan 29175263 Feb 18 01:14 libphp7.so
```

The above file is in this folder:

```
~/apache/modules/
```

Also the php install edited:

```
~/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

I see this entry in there:

```
LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
```

I edited httpd.conf to listen at

```
0.0.0.0:3080
```

I brought up the apache server using

```
~/apache/bin/apachectl start
```

It can serve html files no problem.

I tried the first demo at php.net:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I placed the syntax in:

```
~/apache/htdocs/php10.php
```

When I GET php10.php with curl I see this:

```
dan@nia111:~ $ 
dan@nia111:~ $ curl 0.0.0.0:3080/php10.php
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
dan@nia111:~ $ 
dan@nia111:~ $
```

This is an obvious malfunction.

I should see this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>Hello World</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Question:

How to debug my tech-combo so Apache evaluates the php-syntax in my php file instead of serving it as plain HTML?

I placed copies of

```
~/apache/
```

and

```
~/php/
```

on github so you can study my configuration:

https://github.com/danbikle/php_broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Apache what files should be parsed as PHP. One way to do that is to use this directive:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This tells Apache to parse *.php, *.php3 and *.phtml as PHP, but you could use any extension really.